# PySide QMySql driver on 64 bit Python

Tags: mysql, qt, pyside, mysql-python, qtsql

I read tons of discussions about this topic, and I try to solve it (as suggested many times) compiling PySide and Qt (64 bit) with MySql driver, but it won't work in any way.

**It's possible that using PySide (or PyQt) on Python 2.7 64 bit on Windows I can't use QMySql driver?**

I'm sorry for topic repetition, but no one solution has worked (feel free to correct my english)

EDIT
These are steps I tried:

- run vcvarsall.bat in VisualStudio9.0 for variable configuration for nmake
- download Qt Everywhere 4.8.7
- download MySql 5.5 for Windows x64
- set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2008
- move to Qt dir
- configure -qt-sql-mysql -release -I *(path to mysql include)* -L *(path to mysql libs)* -l libmysql
- run nmake

The problem is that Qt can't link MySql libraries. For instance:
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql...........`

I also tried to link mysql-connector 6.1 x64, but it won't work too.

Comment: You should make explicit what you tried, so that people may propose additional suggestions.

Comment: Which version of qt are you using?

Comment: I use Qt Everywhere 4.8.7